# Memory leak returning QIcon

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt4

I started using Qt but I'm facing a big problem: I implemented my custom model that inhrerits from the QAbstractListModel class. What I want to do is to display a list with icon. All works and the image is shown with my code but it creates a memory leak. If I don't return the icon no memory leak is detected.

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    ...

private:
    QIcon myicon;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    ...

    if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
    {
        return this->myicon;
    }

    ...
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

MyModel::MyModel(...)
{
    ...

    ui.listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("myicon"), "my text"));
}
```

Comment: valgrind? can you show us the output?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm using Windows as dev platform

Comment: What @dschulz means is "shows us the output you used to detect the memory leak"

Comment: It may be "static leak", as QVariant may do some lazy initialization of internal "helper" objects. Repeat operation more then once and check if "leak" is getting bigger

Comment: it could be caused by this bug that seems what I have: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-4341?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a constructor of `QVariant` with `QIcon` as parameter, and I am surprised it compiles. As you are returning a  `QIcon` when a `QVariant` is expected, there must be some crazy implicit conversions going. You have to know that in some cases when you create a `QVariant`there is a deep copy of the initial object. Keep track of the qvariants you create and use `QVariant::clear()` when you don't need them anymore.

**EDIT:**
By the way you are implicitly using the operator

```
QIcon::operator QVariant () const
```

which returns a `QVariant`. this variant doesn't contain the initial `QIcon`, but a deep copy. So follow my earlier advice to get rid of the leak.

Comment: QIcon uses COW and `operator QVarinat` definitely _don not_ create deep copy. Even if it would, that could not lead to memory leak

Comment: I commented my code and added a QListWidget with the QT Designer, after this I wrote the code that I added to my question and tested it. Visual Studio still reports me a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think memory leak is in the code, you showed.

`QIcon` has conversion to `QVarint` (defined with `operator QVariant`), it widely used by standard item model/item widgets.

You also do not manage any pointers and do not use some explicit conversions.

So, this code seems OK, but it can be a memory in code, that *uses* icon.